# Read in Dates from file to be used in plots

Tags: python, date, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to read date stamps in from a data logger and use these dates in plots.  I have been playing with matplotlib dates date2num, datestr2num, and datetime but I keep getting formatting errors and am having trouble finding what the correct syntax and keywords are to do this (and also what they mean).  I have been reading through the matplotlib help with not much luck.  If you have any help or a better way to read in this information I would love the feedback.

```
import numpy as n
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
import matplotlib.dates as d
import datetime as dt


fileobj=open("filename",'r')
data=fileobj.readlines()
fileobj.close()
time=n.empty(len(data))
for i in range(len(data)):
  strings=data[i].split(',')
  if i >5:
    some_time_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(str(strings[0]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    time = d.date2num(some_time_dt)
```

Example data:

```
"2013-02-28 16:53:30",1588,11.85,24.35,22.93,24.1,25.05,22.06,22.2,30.94,21.99,22.7,21.91,22‌​.02,21.79 ,21.72 
"2013-02-28 16:53:31",1589,11.85,24.35,23,24.12,25.05,22.09,22.25,31.19,21.97,22.71,21.91,22‌​.02,21.78 ,21.72
"2013-02-28 16:53:32",1590,11.85,24.35,22.98,24.12,25.05,22.12,22.3,31.35,21.98,22.68,21.9,2‌​2.01,21.7 4,21.69 
"2013-02-28 16:53:33",1591,11.85,24.35,22.95,24.14,25.06,22.15,22.33,31.49,21.96,22.67,21.87‌​,22,21.73 ,21.66
```

March 20,2013
I was able to get this to plot but I need to know how to get rid of the UTC label that prints as the time is not in UTC but in PST.  I would prefer to just not show a timezone at all.

Comment: Consider installing pandas, which has great tools for loading, studying, and plotting time series data. http://pandas.pydata.org/ But, to your question, it will be easier to help you if you can show us a few lines from the file of data you are trying to read in.

Comment: "2013-02-28 16:53:30",1588,11.85,24.35,22.93,24.1,25.05,22.06,22.2,30.94,21.99,22.7,21.91,22.02,21.79
,21.72
"2013-02-28 16:53:31",1589,11.85,24.35,23,24.12,25.05,22.09,22.25,31.19,21.97,22.71,21.91,22.02,21.78
,21.72
"2013-02-28 16:53:32",1590,11.85,24.35,22.98,24.12,25.05,22.12,22.3,31.35,21.98,22.68,21.9,22.01,21.7
4,21.69
"2013-02-28 16:53:33",1591,11.85,24.35,22.95,24.14,25.06,22.15,22.33,31.49,21.96,22.67,21.87,22,21.73
,21.66

Comment: lines begin with dates.  It did not copy very well

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question and pasting there, where it can be formatted. Please fix it if I didn't interpret you correctly.

Comment: ValueError: time data '"2013-02-28 16:27:13"' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to parse the file twice, once for the dates and once for the data:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

D = np.loadtxt("filename",delimiter=",",usecols=[0],dtype="str")
Z = np.loadtxt("filename",delimiter=",",usecols=range(1,10))

DATES = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"') for d in D]
```

You could also use the `converters` argument to pass a lambda function to `loadtxt()` so that it does the string to datetime object conversion for you.  It doesn't save you any lines of code, I'm just noting it for a bit of variety:

```
datey = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"')

D = np.loadtxt("filename",delimiter=",",usecols=[0],
               dtype=dt.datetime,converters={0:datey})
Z = np.loadtxt("filename",delimiter=",",usecols=range(1,10))
```

Comment: From here (the first one) can I use DATES to plot or do I need to do other steps?  Here is some of my output.       [datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 16, 52, 53), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 16, 52, 54), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 16, 52, 55), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 16, 52, 56),

Comment: Yep, `matplotlib` plotting functions will accept that list of datetime objects just fine.  And you can always turn it into a numpy array if a particular function is being stubborn: e.g., `np.array(DATES)`.

Comment: How can I get the UTC to go away. or change it to PST

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this kind of thing with pandas (see my comment above) but here's a rough solution using Python's built-in CSV module.

```
import csv
import datetime
data = []
for row in csv.reader(open('file.txt')):
    row[0] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # Parse date.
    row[1:] = map(float, row[1:]) # Convert data from strings to floats.
    data.append(row)
```

There are fancier ways, but is a straightforward approach.

Running this on the data above, I get

```
[[datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 16, 53, 30), 1588.0, 11.85...], ...]
```

Comment: This did not work either :(  Here's the error I received.      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cwilliams/datetest.py", line 14, in <module>
    row[0] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # Parse date.
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'TOA5' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: The error suggests that the code is trying to parse the setring 'TOA5' as a date. You'll need to skip or remove any rows that container header information. Your code seems to skip 6 lines; my solutions assumes that the file has been prepared so that every line begins with a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the  `"`  from you time string!

If there's only one time per line , i  would change the for loop for something like this:

```
import time as time_module  # there's is a var named time
lineNumber = 0
for line in data:
    lineNumber += 1
    if line <= 5:
        continue  # skip the first 5 lines

    line = line.split(',')
    timeString = line[0].strip('"')
    print timeString
    print time_module.strptime(timeString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    time = d.date2num(time_module.strptime(timeString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```